# How to invoke a GET request on a secured host's URL (Https://) using RobotFramework RequestsLibrary?

Tags: ssl, openssl, httprequest, robotframework, pem

I have a password protected '.p12' file for the host where I am trying to invoke a GET method on this host using the converted '.pem' file. But when I make this call through RobotFramework, I get following error:

```
SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:661)
```

I did below steps:

1. Convert the .p12 file to .pem file containing both - certificate and keys.

   ```
   openssl pkcs12 -in <input_file>.p12 -out <output_file>.pem -nodes -passin pass:<password>
   ```
2. Call the GET method by passing the .pem file in verify option

   ```
   *** Settings ***
   Library    RequestsLibrary
   ..
   ..
   *** Keywords ***
   Call HTTPS GET method
       Create Session    my_session   https://<host>/<port>       verify=${CURDIR}${/}<output_file>.pem    debug=3

       ${response} =    Get Request    my_session    <uri>
       ..
       ..
   ```

When I use the same pem certificate and make the call from postman, it works perfectly fine. What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you sure the path to the file is resolved correctly - this part here - `${CURDIR}${/}<output_file>.pem`? Could you try with an absolute path, and see does this change anything?

Comment: Yes, I am. I provided diff path for non-existant file and the error mesage was changed.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the solution. I am not sure if its the legit one, but its working for me. 
I believe there was a parameter missed to pass in the RequestKeywords.py in RequestsLibrary.

Left is the file from std Library and right is the one I updated.

[image]

With this change, its working perfectly. As the underlying python library requests expects the file details in cert variable, not in verify.